# How can I check if a String containing a qualified class name is an Exception class in java?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Class<Throwable> createClass(String className){
    try {
        Class<Throwable> convertedClass = (Class<Throwable>)Class.forName(className);
        return convertedClass;
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | ClassCastException ex){
         LOG.error("Unable to convert exception class due to exception. Skipping this whitelisted exception class, {}. Please check your configurations.",className);
         LOG.error("Exception thrown while converting exception type.",ex);
         return null;
    }
}
```

Essentially, I would like to ensure that the converted class is an exception. If so, then return the class, otherwise, return null. I thought that by returning a `Class<Throwable>`, it would ensure that the class is of that type, but it isn't working that way. If I pass in `java.lang.String` as the `className`, I get back a `Class<String>` instead of `null`. I was expecting that a ClassCastException would be thrown given that Class is not the same as Class, but I figure that Generics plays a role in why this would work. Does anyone know of a way to return back only a `Throwable` type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class#isAssignableFrom` to check if the `Class` is a `Throwable`.

```
private Class<?> createClass(String className){
    try{
        Class<?> convertedClass = Class.forName(className);
        if(Throwable.class.isAssignableFrom(convertedClass)) return convertedClass;
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
        LOG.error("Unable to convert exception class due to exception. Skipping this whitelisted exception class, {}. Please check your configurations.",className);
        LOG.error("Exception thrown while converting exception type.",ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `asSubclass` is a considerably better option here. The method return type can also be much improved.

Comment: See my example. Superior in every way: Less code, intent is clearer, return type is better, no ugly-cast required. (uglycast: One that causes the compiler to emit warnings). This code is __also actively broken__: If you pass in an FQN that _is_ a class that can be loaded, but _is not an exception type_, then this code will SILENTLY return null. The catching of CCEx is useless, and no log error is emitted. See how this code is considerably worse? I rest my case. Neither Unmitigated, nor you, spotted the error, clearly.

Comment: @rzwitserloot The cast is simply hidden when using `asSubclass`.

Comment: @Unmitigated Yup. Your code has a bug, which your eyes didn't spot, which sort of proves my point, no?

Comment: @rzwitserloot i think the intent is clearer when using `isAssignableFrom`. I still don't agree with this answer being "considerably worse". I actually prefer this one.

Comment: @rzwitserloot That's what the OP wants. "Essentially, I would like to ensure that the converted class is an exception. If so, then return the class, otherwise, return null."

Comment: @rzwitserloot Additionally, while the behavior of my method is intended, your code [fails to compile](https://ideone.com/LqIuCL), which does not seem to show that the intent is clearer.

Comment: You're clearly grasping at straws and unwilling to acknowledge that you're fallible. The try block cannot possibly throw ClassCastException and yet you are catching it. This is 'intentional'? That makes no sense.

Comment: @rzwitserloot That's a different matter altogether. The behavior of returning `null` is intentional. You are right that it is unnecessary to catch `ClassCastException`, but that is not what I was responding to (as it was not mentioned previously).

Answer (score 1):

> `Class<Throwable> convertedClass = (Class<Throwable>)Class.forName(className);`

As the warning that the compiler spits out will tell you, **this is extremely dangerous**. The bits in `<>` inside the 'type' part of a cast operation (the `T` in `(SomeType<T>) expr`) are **assertions**. You are telling the compiler to assume that it WILL be the case and to stop whining about it. **No runtime check is done**. There is therefore, at runtime, absolutely no guarantee that the provided class is a `Class<Throwable>`. It is in fact 99.9999% likely that it is not, because **ONLY** literally `Throwable.class` is the correct type; all other throwables would at best be a `Class<? extends Throwable>` because generics are invariant.

So, you end up with a variable typed `Class<Throwable>` that doesn't actually contain that. For the -non-generics part of the typing system, you CANNOT end up with the 'wrong' thing, the java compiler and class verifier work together to guarantee that 100%. But for generics, that guarantee is off the table. You can have a `List<Number>` containing a string, no problem.

The upshot is that some code down the line that interacts with this 'faulty' `Class<Throwable>` type ends up getting a `ClassCastException`, **even if no cast is involved**.

The fix is to never use generics in a cast operator, other than `<?>` which can't go wrong in that sense, unless you really know what you are doing.

What you want, presumably, is this:

```
Class<? extends Throwable> fixed =
  Throwable.class.asSubclass(Class.forName(className));
```

As the [javadoc of `asSubclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass-java.lang.Class-) explains, this will:

1. Check if the argument (`Class.forName(className)`) here is either literally `Throwable.class`, or some subtype thereof.
2. If no, that call does not complete normally and instead a `ClassCastException` is thrown. You can catch it, if you like.
3. If it is, then the same class object is returned, but the expression is updated to be of type `Class<? extends Throwable>`.

This saves you an 'ugly-cast' (a cast that generates a warning).

General tip: If the compiler emits a warning and you don't get it? You should hold strongly the belief that your code is broken as designed. Find another way, do some research, or try to understand the warning. The compiler doesn't toss does in your face for funsies. Treat warnings as errors unless you are extremely sure you know exactly what you're doing.

---

This gets you to:

```
private Class<? extends Throwable> createClass(String className) {
    try {
        return Throwable.class.asSubclass(Class.forName(className));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | ClassCastException e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to convert exception class due to exception. Skipping this whitelisted exception class, {}. Please check your configurations.", className);
            return null;
    }
}
```

NB: The return type your method has is fundamentally broken. It must be `Class<? extends Throwable>`. I also removed a log line - it seemed quite useless.